# Postfix and dovecot. TLS not available

Tags: ssl, postfix, dovecot, sasl

I've been trying to setup a send only SMTP server with postfix and dovecot, on Ubuntu 16.04. The problem I'm having is that when trying to send an email I get the message back.

> 4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problem

So I'm guessing that the problem lies within my postfix TLS setup. And if I'm checking the status of the postfix service

> Sep 19 15:03:15 mail.example.org postfix[3571]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_tls_session_cache_header=yes
>   Sep 19 15:03:15 mail.example.org postfix[3571]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_tls_note_starttls_offer=yes
>   Sep 19 15:03:15 mail.example.org postfix[3571]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_tls_recieved_header=yes

So I'm guessing it has something to do with these settings. But I don't get exactly whats wrong with them, I've tried removing the lines, and the error still occurs.

Postfix Config:

```
mydomain = branelmail.dk
myhostname = mail.branelmail.dk

myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost

unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

home_mailbox = /dev/null

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

debug_peer_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/mail.branelmail.dk.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/mail.branelmail.dk.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# You can use log level 3 or 4 for more advanced troubleshooting
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 4

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
relayhost =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
#smtpd_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
#smtpd_tls_recieved_header = yes
#smtpd_tls_session_cache_header = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

Comment: Please add your postfix config to the question.

Comment: The message sounds like it occurs when your mailserver tries to connect to other mailservers. You could try setting `smtp_tls_security_level = may`, the default value for that directive is `none`. Do you get any additional messages in the log file regarding TLS, maybe on server startup?

Comment: I don't get anything special in the log file. All I get is 
Sep 19 16:11:14 mail postfix[4467]: Postfix is running with backwards-compatible default settings

Sep 19 16:11:14 mail postfix[4467]: See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html for details

Sep 19 16:11:14 mail postfix[4467]: To disable backwards compatibility use "postconf compatibility_level=2" and "postfix reload"

Sep 19 16:11:14 mail postfix/master[4504]: daemon started -- version 3.1.0, configuration /etc/postfix

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i found a solution, it seems that there was something wrong with the certificate we generated, after buying a certificate online, it works wit no problem. So if anyone has the same problem, just make sure that the certificates your using, are properly setup.